# How to implement a perfect branch predictor in gem5

Tags: gem5

I am new to gem5 and want to reason about the impact of branch prediction on processor performance.
Now I need to implement a perfect branch predictor in the gem5 ooo CPU model, which means the branch predictions are always correct. Is there any simple way to implement this predictor or just make instruction fetch perfect in the gem5 ooo CPU model?
the version of gem5 I am using is 21.1.0.2.

Comment: How can a branch prediction always be correct? If you could do that you could simply optimize to eliminate the branch completely.

Comment: I record the trace from the commit stage for branch instructions to get the right branch prediction and branch target. And I replay this trace in my second run for this elf file. Now I am stuck in modifying the branch unit to use the trace file to make perfect branch prediction.